# No Cloud Services Listed in Visual Studio 2013 Server Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, azure

When I connect to azure via the Server manager all of my storage accounts, service bus, virtual machines and sql azure instances are listed, but only one Cloud service of many (10 or so) is showing up.  I have made sure that I'm not filtering anything and checked with other members of my dev team.  They are seeing the same thing. I have tried creating a new service via the azure management portal in different regions, but none of them show up.  I can also enumerate the cloud services using powershell without any problem. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Are these cloud services using different accounts or MSDN accounts? What is the admin structure?  Are you logged in with the admin account or a Live account?

Comment: thank you for the response. we have a single azure account that we're using. I'm logged in as an admin and have also tried logging in using the master account with the same results. When we originally set up our accounts they were connected through the windows Live, so all of our users have always had to log in that way. We have had some login issues in the past which I think were connected to this (having to login in and out multiple times before being able to access the management portal.) Also I should mention that when I log in to the portal I can see all of the services.

Comment: By "azure account" I mean subscription.

Comment: When you log into the portal with the admin account...the admin account is set up as the admin off all the other Live accounts?  can you double check that in the portal?  If you have an enterprise account, that might not work you will need the admin Live account that has the MSDN/Live subs under it.  BTW I just verified this on the two Azure accounts I am admin off..in one of them I have over 20+ MSDN/Live Azure accounts and in Vis Studio 2013/SDK 2.2 I can see all of the services created under those accounts with a single admin account.

Comment: I can see all of the other accounts listed as "co-administrators". Even when I sign in to visual studio as the service administrator I cannot see the correct number of cloud services.

Comment: And to clarify, you don't have an enterprise account which you are using to log in?

Answer (score 0):

It happens once a while also for me that I dont see all services in VS2013. Normaly right clickign azure node and manage subscriptions and signing out and in solves the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cloud Services that host IaaS virtual machine are not currently displayed in the Server Explorer Cloud Services node.  You can still see the virtual machine instances under the Virtual Machine node.  This has nothing to do with filtering.  It is just a point-in-time limitation of server explorer that hopefully will be corrected in a future release.